# python - refactoring - generalizing derived classes

Tags: python, refactoring

I have following piece of code in `Python`. There are two classes `A2` and `B2` which share functions `f1()` and `f2()`. They differ in their base classes, deriving from `A` and `B` respectively.

I can see how to generalize this in `C++` using `templates`. But I am not sure how to do this `Python`.

```
class A2(A):   
    def __init__(self):   
        A.__init__(self)   
        self._Z = Z('high')

    def f1(self):   
        return self._Z.f1() 

    def f2(self):   
        return self._Z.f2() 

    # ... more functions ...


class B2(B):   
    def __init__(self):   
        B.__init__(self)   
        self._Z = Z('low')

    def f1(self):   
        return self._Z.f1() 

    def f2(self):   
        return self._Z.f2() 

    # ... more functions ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you might try a mixin class:

```
class Mixin(object):

    def f1(self):   
        return self._Z.f1() 

    def f2(self):   
        return self._Z.f2() 


class A2(A, Mixin): 

    def __init__(self):   
        A.__init__(self)   
        self._Z = Z('high')


class B2(B, Mixin):   
    def __init__(self):   
        B.__init__(self)   
        self._Z = Z('low')
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid Multiple Inheritance?

Comment: @Anand have `A` and `B` inherit from `Mixin`. But why?

Comment: Python does not have the same problems with multiple inheritance that C++ does.

Comment: @LukasGraf Little scared of Multiple inheritance. Can this be solved using metaprogramming methods?

Comment: @Anand Yes, it can. For instance, you could use a class decorator to define the common methods. But mixin classes are an establish pattern in Python, and are the simplest solution to your dilemma. Metaprogramming is cool, but simplicity > cool.

Comment: See the definition of `namedtuple` in the `collections` module. Metaprogramming is probably going to be harder to get right than using a mixing.